# Spotfire hyperlink in cross table

Tags: spotfire

Has anyone able to make a column to be hyperlink in cross table in Spotfire? I can set the column to Link Render in regular table, but not in cross table.

Comment: Related forum thread: https://community.tibco.com/questions/hyperlink-cross-table

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported in Spotfire cross tables.  However, you can use a graphical table and configure it such that clicking on a cell will navigate to a target url by configuring the "Action" button in the Axes settings so that it will perform an action upon click, and then use a small IronPython script to open the target url in a browser

Comment: From my investigations, this will only work in the so-called "thick client" and not in the webplayer.  Both pop-up windows and opening links via IronPython only worked in the prior and not the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible in crosstable. As @TWAndrews says, you can use a graphical table and for example, create an icon and perform action on click on this icon. This action could be a link to navigate in the Dashboard, a `http://` link, and more other possibilities. 
Use a link in a crosstable will work in webplayer and in computer software.